# Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading

Tags: angularjs

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
newMaster.html:28 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:57951/testfe/startup/../testStartup.js at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] 
(node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:29) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask

(zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:35) at Zone.runTask 
(node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:47) at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke

(/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:33)Error loading http://localhost:57951/testfe/startup/../testStartup.js

Comment: Package.json FILE

Comment: Please edit your question and include `package.json` in itself. Don't post it as an answer.